# How to Redirect to IdentityServer Login When Token Expires C#.Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

Good day,

I am new to IdentityServer and I've used their quickstart guide to set it up. However, I do not know how to redirect to the IdentityServer login page after token expires? Here is my current client config in startup.cs

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("cookie")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorityUrl"];
            options.ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/Home/Index";

            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.UsePkce = true;
            options.ResponseMode = "query";

            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.SaveTokens = true;

        });
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In first request to Resource Serve after token expiration, Resource Server will redirect client to IDP.

Comment: Hey did you figure out how to do redirect the user to the login page upon token expiration?